# Parse more than one parameter value in serializers.IntegerField(validators=...)

Tags: mysql, django, serialization

I'm using `django` with `mysql`.

In `serializers.py` I have:

```
class UserWorseQuestListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[user_exists])
    section_id = serializers.IntegerField(validators=[section_exists_in_completed_quest])
```

and my `section_exists_in_completed_quest` contains:

```
def section_exists_in_completed_quest(section_id):
    if section_id is None:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('section_id must be specified')
    quest_ids = CompletedQuestion.objects.filter(question__section_id = section_id) \
    .values_list("question_id", flat=True).distinct()
    #print (quest_ids)
    if not quest_ids:
        msg = 'Completed questions in Section {} were not found for user {}'
        raise serializers.ValidationError(msg.format(section_id))
```

My question is whether I can pass the value of `user_id` in `section_exists_in_completed_quest()` in someway.

If I pass it like `def section_exists_in_completed_quest(section_id, user_id):` I get `HTTP/1.1" 500 27` error.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since up to know I found no solution, this is what I propose using [SessionStore()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views):

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore

s = SessionStore()

def user_exists(user_id):
    if user_id is None:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('user_id must be specified')
    if not User.objects.filter(id=user_id).exists():
        msg = 'User {} not found'
        raise serializers.ValidationError(msg.format(user_id))
    s['user_id']= user_id

def section_exists_in_completed_quest(section_id):
    if section_id is None:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('section_id must be specified')
    quest_ids = CompletedQuestion.objects.filter(user_id__exact=s['user_id'] ,question__section_id = section_id) \
    .values_list("question_id", flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: This might work when in testing when you are processing a single request at a time, but you might start to get odd results when your server is handling multiple requests at once.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a validator, you can write a `validate` method which can access multiple fields.

```
class UserWorseQuestListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[user_exists])
    section_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    def validate(self):
        section_id = data['section_id']
        user_id = data['user_id']
        ...
```

See the docs on [object level validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation) for more info.